# Substring string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, substring

I got this string:

```
xavier.blodot
wisoyo.hadi
```

And I want this output: firstletter+lastname

```
xblodot
whadi
```

Regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this approach:

```
sed -r 's:(.).*\.(.+):\1\.\2:g' {YOUR_FILE.TXT}
```

Comment: That prints `x.blodot` and `w.hadi` instead of `xblodot` and `whadi`. Maybe just drop the `\.` in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Another bit smaller `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^(.)[^.]+\./\1/' file

xblodot
whadi
```

Or using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F. '{print substr($1,1,1) $2}' file

xblodot
whadi
```

Answer (score 1):

The title says *in `bash`*, so I’m assuming it must be in `bash` *only* (without using `sed`, `awk` or other external processes):

```sh
while read ns; do
  echo "${ns::1}${ns#*.}"
done < the_input_file.txt
```

Making it more resilient, if needed, is up to you. It depends on how much you (dis)trust the input. This may include, for example, `IFS= read -r ns`, a check that `[[ "$ns" == +([a-z]).+([a-z]) ]]`, and arbitrary other consistency checks.

Answer (score 1):

```
name=xavier.blodot
shortened_name="${name:0:1}${name##*.}"
```

You would have to catch the case, when the name does not contain a period.